# Sybase ASE issue dropping unique constraint

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sybase-asa

When dropping a unique constraint both using Sybase Central or iSQL, the drop statement shown is as follows;

```
alter table user_database.dbo.table_name drop constraint contraint_name
```

But execution fails with different errors, like this:

If constraint name is between single quotes, the command returns:

Incorrect syntax near the word 'constraint'

If constraint name is between square braquets, the command returns:

The identifier that starts with '[constraint_name' is too long. Maximum lenght is 28.

If constraint name is written alone, the command returns

Incorrect syntax near '.'

I'm 'sa' user and I've tried issuing commands from both master and user_database. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any quotes or brackets, and pls post the full final statement. Also try leaving off the db name (make sure you are in that database).